# How create array from comma separated string, sort it low to high, then join it back into comma separated string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is what I am trying so far.Any ideas are appreciated.

```
var orders = '1115672,1115676,1115677,1115682,1115684,';
var array = new Array();
array = orders.split(',');
orders = array.sort(function(a, b){return a - b;});
orders = orders.sort((a, b) => a - b);
orders = orders.join(",");
```

It is returning ,,,,,11156721115676111567711156821115684.

Comment: Just as a comment, on this kind of exercises I allways try to give the input sorted in a worng way, so I can really check if the code is sorting correctly or not.

Comment: On Chrome, I don't get the same output you do, I get `",1115672,1115676,1115677,1115682,1115684"`.   FWIW, there's no need to call sort twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is splitting the string in specified places, in your case - comma `,`. Then use simple sort function and then you just have to join it, again with the comma sign.

```js
var orders = '1115672,1115676,1115677,1115682,1115684';

console.log(orders.split(',').sort((a,b) => a-b).join(','));
```

Comment: I tried this, but it is doing the same thing. So the site I am modifying is returning with the extra comma at the end of the string. would that cause any problems?

Comment: @Ryan according to my tests that _should_ only result in an extra (empty) field at the start of the list

Comment: Your code is functionally equivalent to what the OP posted, and doesn't explain his code's alleged output

Comment: I agree that your code should work. the string must be outputting differently than I thought. I will try to figure out what the string is actually outputting.

Comment: Thanks for the help turns out I was in a foreach...It now works as intended after putting this outside the foreach.

Comment: @Ryan I was busy answering to someone. Do you have still any problems?

Comment: I was running your code within a foreach where the string was being created so that is why it was messing up. Once I moved it out of the foreach it worked.